# Why can't I install any packages on Pycharm?

Tags: python, python3, api, pycharm

These are the three main resources I've been mainly using to try to either use the Google Sheets API or manipulate an excel spreadsheet on Pycharm:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnPlKLEGR7E&t=196s

For this link this is the error I get: **[Not installing gspread Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REEkc.png)**

- https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial

When I try to install pandas I get this: **[Not installing pandas Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V7Py.png)**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZkemP6RCu_w&t=39s

On this link, once you get to time 2:13 (it shows the available packages to download from the settings), nothing seems to come up on my screen.Yes I have googled these, but I'm pretty new to this so I don't know exactly where to go from here. Doing this project with Excel was my work around to not being able to work with google sheets, but I'm kind of stuck now.

*Assume I've followed the steps mentioned here, which I have. If you don't want to watch the first youtube video since it's pretty long, here's a tutorial he wrote on his website exactly the way he did it on the video:

- https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/google-sheets-python-api-tutorial/

Comment: Note that you can always manually install packages from PyPI -- [oauth2client](https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/#files) - [gspread](https://pypi.org/project/gspread/#files) - [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files). Note, however, that those modules likely have dependencies (such as `numpy` for `pandas`) that may also need to be manually downloaded as well (tedious but doable).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the solution. To be honest a guy at work solved it. It was something I probably wasn't gonna figure out unless someone from work new what they were doing due to our proxy servers. But basically there's a very specific way I had to set up my proxy. But now all I have to is is go into the terminal and type

> SET http_proxy=http://(PROXY ADDRESS):PORT
>
> SET https_proxy=https://(PROXY ADDRESS):PORT

I tried doing all this on my personal computer and I did not have any issues installing anything. That's what got me going around asking for help at work